# JS Проблема с реализацией воспроизведением звука в таймере обратного отсчёта

Tags: javascript, таймер

Всем доброго времени суток! Прошу вас о помощи. Нашёл таймер обратного отсчёта, решил доделать. После того как таймер останавливается, воспроизводится мелодия. Проблема заключается в том, что мелодия не проигрывается. Тык-мык, не получилось. Помогите!!!
PS:Строго код не судите, только учусь!

```js
function music() {
  var snd = new Audio("file:///android_asset/music/saxophone.mp3");
  snd.play();
}

var snd = new Audio("file:///android_asset/music/saxophone.mp3");

function refresh() {

  document.getElementById("timer").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("spisok_h").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("spisok_m").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("spisok_s").style.display = "none";


  ;
  (function() {
    'use strict';

  })();

  // значение времени на момент запуска скрипта
  var now = new Date(),
    // массив данных в котором находятся значения оставшихся
    // часов, минут и секунд соответственно, которые мы получаем
    // путём вычитания из их максимального значения текущего
    times = [
      document.getElementById("spisok_h").value,
      document.getElementById("spisok_m").value,
      document.getElementById("spisok_s").value,
    ],
    // получаем объекты, в которые будем выводить показания таймера
    hBox = document.getElementById('hour'),
    mBox = document.getElementById('minutes'),
    sBox = document.getElementById('seconds');

  timer(times);

  function timer(times) {
    // объявляем идентификатор таймера и запускаем функцию 'setInterval'
    var tm = setInterval(function() {

      // уменьшаем значение секунд на 1
      times[2]--;

      // проверяем, не обнулился ли таймер и если да, то останавливаем 'setInterval'
      if (times[0] == 0 && times[1] == 0 && times[2] == 0) {
        music();

        clearInterval(tm);
        document.getElementById("timer").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("spisok_h").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("spisok_m").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("spisok_s").style.display = "block";



      } else if (times[2] == -1) {
        // если секунды имеют отрицательное значение, это значит, что
        // они перешли 0 и должен начаться отсчёт новой минуты,
        // при этом секунды становятся равными своему максимальному значению - 59,
        // а минуты уменьшаются на 1
        times[2] = 59;
        times[1]--;
      } else if (times[1] == -1) {
        // аналогично, как для минут и секунд
        // минуты выставляем в значение 59, а час уменьшаем на 1
        times[1] = 59;
        times[0]--;
      }

      // если показания или часов, или минут, или секунд меньше 10,
      // ставим перед показанием ноль
      var h = (times[0] < 10) ? '0' + times[0] : times[0],
        m = (times[1] < 10) ? '0' + times[1] : times[1],
        s = (times[2] < 10) ? '0' + times[2] : times[2];

      // выводим значение таймера на экран
      showTimer(h, m, s);

    }, 1000);
  }


  function showTimer(hour, min, sec) {
    hBox.innerHTML = hour;
    mBox.innerHTML = min;
    sBox.innerHTML = sec;

  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mesto_timer">
  <div>Time<br>
    <span id="timer" class="timer">
      <span id="hour">00</span>:
      <span id="minutes">00</span>:
      <span id="seconds">00</span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <button class="button" id="bt_4" onclick="refresh()">Start</button>

  <select class="spisok_h" id="spisok_h">
    <option>Hours</option>
    <option value="0">00</option>
    <option value="1">01</option>
    <option value="2">02</option>
    <option value="3">03</option>
    <option value="4">04</option>
    <option value="5">05</option>
    <option value="6">06</option>
    <option value="7">07</option>
    <option value="8">08</option>
    <option value="9">09</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>11</option>
    <option>12</option>
    <option>13</option>
    <option>14</option>
    <option>15</option>
    <option>16</option>
    <option>17</option>
    <option>18</option>
    <option>19</option>
    <option>20</option>
    <option>21</option>
    <option>22</option>
    <option>23</option>
    <option>24</option>
  </select>

  <select class="spisok_m" id="spisok_m">
    <option>Minutes</option>
    <option value="0">00</option>
    <option value="1">01</option>
    <option value="2">02</option>
    <option value="3">03</option>
    <option value="4">04</option>
    <option value="5">05</option>
    <option value="6">06</option>
    <option value="7">07</option>
    <option value="8">08</option>
    <option value="9">09</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>11</option>
    <option>12</option>
    <option>13</option>
    <option>14</option>
    <option>15</option>
    <option>16</option>
    <option>17</option>
    <option>18</option>
    <option>19</option>
    <option>20</option>
    <option>21</option>
    <option>22</option>
    <option>23</option>
    <option>24</option>
    <option>25</option>
    <option>26</option>
    <option>27</option>
    <option>28</option>
    <option>29</option>
    <option>30</option>
    <option>31</option>
    <option>32</option>
    <option>33</option>
    <option>34</option>
    <option>35</option>
    <option>36</option>
    <option>37</option>
    <option>38</option>
    <option>39</option>
    <option>40</option>
    <option>41</option>
    <option>42</option>
    <option>43</option>
    <option>44</option>
    <option>45</option>
    <option>46</option>
    <option>47</option>
    <option>48</option>
    <option>49</option>
    <option>50</option>
    <option>51</option>
    <option>52</option>
    <option>53</option>
    <option>54</option>
    <option>55</option>
    <option>56</option>
    <option>57</option>
    <option>58</option>
    <option>59</option>
  </select>

  <select class="spisok_s" id="spisok_s">
    <option>Seconds</option>
    <option value="0">00</option>
    <option value="1">01</option>
    <option value="2">02</option>
    <option value="3">03</option>
    <option value="4">04</option>
    <option value="5">05</option>
    <option value="6">06</option>
    <option value="7">07</option>
    <option value="8">08</option>
    <option value="9">09</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>11</option>
    <option>12</option>
    <option>13</option>
    <option>14</option>
    <option>15</option>
    <option>16</option>
    <option>17</option>
    <option>18</option>
    <option>19</option>
    <option>20</option>
    <option>21</option>
    <option>22</option>
    <option>23</option>
    <option>24</option>
    <option>25</option>
    <option>26</option>
    <option>27</option>
    <option>28</option>
    <option>29</option>
    <option>30</option>
    <option>31</option>
    <option>32</option>
    <option>33</option>
    <option>34</option>
    <option>35</option>
    <option>36</option>
    <option>37</option>
    <option>38</option>
    <option>39</option>
    <option>40</option>
    <option>41</option>
    <option>42</option>
    <option>43</option>
    <option>44</option>
    <option>45</option>
    <option>46</option>
    <option>47</option>
    <option>48</option>
    <option>49</option>
    <option>50</option>
    <option>51</option>
    <option>52</option>
    <option>53</option>
    <option>54</option>
    <option>55</option>
    <option>56</option>
    <option>57</option>
    <option>58</option>
    <option>59</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: А просто вызов `music()` при клике на кнопку, без всяких таймеров, проигрывает музыку?

Comment: кажется, что аудио должно загрузиться, перед там как ее можно проигрывать

Comment: Да, музыка проигрывается, если использовать кнопку

Comment: По поводу загрузки - не знаю, но если вставить в любой другой фрагмент кода вызов функции music(), то проигрывается

Comment: а вы уверены, что у вас вообще `music` вызывается, Если включить таймер, то после нуля будут идти цифры 59, 58...

Comment: Да, уверен. Про проблему с 59,58 и тд знаю, если поставить таймер на 1 секунду, появляется сбой и появляется 59, 58 и др

Comment: Кстати, только сейчас заметил. После функции music случайно поставил повторное объявление переменной snd, это не как не влияло на сам код

Comment: Автовоспроизведение - это не только по ходу загрузки страницы, это после выполнения условия или задержки. В текущих версиях нужно кликнуть хотя бы в любом месте на странице, чтобы заработал авторежим.